# Order of evaluation of function arguments in PHP

Tags: php, evaluation, operator-precedence

Is order of evaluation of PHP function arguments guaranteed to be always the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example where it might make a difference…?

Comment: Like in some exotic scenario where a variable would get modified within an expression passed as a function argument, while using the same variable as a different function argument in the same call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, yes. As [the manual states](https://secure.php.net/manual/functions.arguments.php):

> [Function] arguments are evaluated from left to right.

But there are two edge cases where *arguments are not evaluated at all*:

## Undefined functions

```
$calls = 0;
register_shutdown_function(function () use (&$calls) {
    echo $calls;
});
func_does_not_exist($calls++);
```

This [outputs](https://3v4l.org/MkJWV) `0` on all versions of PHP.

## Missing constructor, a special case of an undefined function

```
class Foo {}

$bar = 0;
$foo = new Foo($bar++);
echo $bar;
```

This [outputs](https://3v4l.org/WracQ) `0` on PHP < 7.1, and `1` on PHP >= 7.1. It's been called the "Rasmus optimization", and it occurs only in the case of constructing classes without formal constructors. See also [#67829](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67829), [#54162](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54162) and [#54170](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54170).

---

In summary, the manual is correct. For defined functions, arguments are evaluated left-to-right then passed into the function. Undefined functions, for which a non-existent constructor is a special case, do not qualify as functions and so the evaluation before calling is itself undefined.

Comment: 54161 doesn't look particularly… relevant.

Comment: As long as it only happens with bug report numbers…

Comment: Thanks for being my test case, @deceze. :)

Comment: It's not really any different from short-circuiting elsewhere (e.g. `false && $bar++`) -  the result isn't going to get used, so don't bother evaluating it. Not remotely as intuitive, though.

Answer (score 4):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

> Information may be passed to functions via the argument list, which is a comma-delimited list of expressions. The arguments are evaluated from left to right.

In theory it might change in future versions of PHP, but I certainly wouldn't expect it to.

(And please don't write any code that relies on it, for everyone's sake...)